# Is there any way to manage/manupulate ElasticSearch indices, when it's not running?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a single-node **EalsticSearch** that currently has too many shards (in comparison to its server hardware) and those (lots of shards) stop ElasticSearch from working. I want to select just some of my indices (and shards) to be served by my ElasticSearch. Is there any way to filter/close ElaticSearch indices when it's not running

Comment: This http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v will help you to find out the indices which are there in your instance. Then you can close and open by sending a POST to `/{index}/_close` and `/{index}/_open`

Comment: Since your ES is turned off, what you can try to do is to move indices you don't need away from your $ES_DATA folder to somewhere else. Keep just the indices you need so that ES can start.

Comment: @Val Isn't there any CLI tool to manipulate indices? without removing files and folders manually! I want to keep the stat safe as much as possible and don't miss any side effects for closing/removing indices!

Comment: If your ES is turned off, even a CLI tool would not be able to do much more than copying/moving the folders where the indices are located.